# If an ellipse has two radiuses, is there something like it, but with three or more radiuses?

Tags: circles, conic-sections

If we say that a circle has one radius, and an ellipse has two, can I define figures that have three, four, or more radiuses?

Also, how can I get that "radius"? In an ellipse that is 10 at its shortest, and 20 at its longest, obviously, at 0°, the "radius" is 10, and at 90° it's 20(well, depends on its angle I guess), is there a formulate I can use to calculate that?

Not particularly knowledgeable about math, hope my question makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

One answer to your question is provided by an ellipsoid, a three dimensional version of an ellipse, which has three 'radii.' See: http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipsoid

You also asked for an equation to measure the radius at any angle - for that, see here, the section "Polar form relative to center." http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipse

Comment: I'm not looking for a 3D version, but rather something that is drawn like a circle(sin(a)*r, cos(a)*r, I'm a coder), but where r varies depending on the angle, like in an ellipse, but with more different radii. (should correct my post to radii, but oh well)

Comment: I suppose one way to think about this would be to consider a double pendulum (or triple pendulum, or quadruple pendulum, or...). Depending on how the segments of the pendulum move relative to one another, you can get very complicated shapes.

Comment: If you can install Love2D, check out this program of mine(just don't look at the source code, please, haha): https://www.dropbox.com/s/rakmhr57t68bz5f/asmostuff_with_angles.love - if you press 1 or 2, you get low vertex count polygons, which I compute essentially from a list of "radii" that represent the... uh, the whole thing is hairy, well, I guess you'll get the idea looking at it n.n

Comment: Also, ignore the fact that the purple lines intersect circles - that was just test code, and I figured out how to bypass that for what I will be using the whole thing for(which is raycasting)